# "sslv3 alert handshake failure" on ruby 2

Tags: ruby, ssl, ruby-2.3

I am trying to use a webservice with ruby, but it seems to be an issue with it's SSL configuration and ruby 2:

```
>> require "open-uri"
=> true
>> open("https://w390w.gipuzkoa.net/WAS/HACI/HFAServiciosProveedoresWEB/services/FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort") {|f| p f.content_type }
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I've tried with curl and openssl and it works:

```
curl https://w390w.gipuzkoa.net/WAS/HACI/HFAServiciosProveedoresWEB/services/FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort
openssl s_client -connect w390w.gipuzkoa.net:443
```

it also works with ruby 1.9:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "open-uri"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> open("https://w390w.gipuzkoa.net/WAS/HACI/HFAServiciosProveedoresWEB/services/FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort") {|f| p f.content_type }
"text/html"
```

with ruby 2, I've tried using TLS, without success

```
>> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = :TLSv1
=> :TLSv1
>> open("https://w390w.gipuzkoa.net/WAS/HACI/HFAServiciosProveedoresWEB/services/FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort") {|f| p f.content_type }
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert handshake failure

>> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = :TLSv1_2
=> :TLSv1_2
>> open("https://w390w.gipuzkoa.net/WAS/HACI/HFAServiciosProveedoresWEB/services/FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort") {|f| p f.content_type }
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: wrong version number
```

checking server SSL configuration on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=w390w.gipuzkoa.net it returns this error: "Assessment failed: Unexpected failure", since I can access several similar webservices with ruby 2, I guess they have something miss-configured.

any ideas how can I access this webservice with ruby 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite a poor configuration for a server. [Comodo's SSL Analyzer](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=w390w.gipuzkoa.net) appears to be more lenient and shows the four supported cipher suites.
[image: Cipher suites section from SSL Analyzer] Also, the server supports TLSv1.0.

Now, I cannot find a resource online that indicates if these cipher suites were disabled by default in Ruby 2, but here's something you can try:

1. Enable the best of the ciphers using `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ciphers] = "DES-CBC3-SHA"`
   Cipher name obtained from [OpenSSL ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html).
2. Attempting to connect now should display this error as the site's CA isn't trusted:

   > OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3
   >   read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
3. You can add this CA using `ssl_ca_cert` or bypass verification (not recommended) using `ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`. E.g.,

   ```
   open("https://w390w.gipuzkoa.net/WAS/HACI/HFAServiciosProveedoresWEB/services/FacturaSSPPWebServiceProxyPort", {ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}) {|f| p f.content_type }
   ```

You can also give Net::HTTP a shot.

Comment: thanks! with `DES-CBC3-SHA` it works, and thanks for the ciphers list, it's hard to find, a link on the ruby doc would be very useful!

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html or `man ciphers`

Answer (score 2):

The server supports only very few ciphers, most of the completely insecure (export ciphers, DES-CBC-SHA) and the only at least a bit secure cipher (DES-CBC3-SHA) is considered insecure since [Sweet32](https://sweet32.info/). Chances are high that because of this insecurity modern TLS stacks in the client will fail with the handshake.